# Why does my onClick handler not log out the latest version of state and how can I troubleshoot this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-hooks-jl3qx?file=/src/App.js)

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  let [button, setButton] = useState(null);
  let [num, setNum] = useState(5);

  function revealState() {
    console.log(num);
  }
  function changeState() {
    setNum(Math.random());
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const el = (
      <button id="logStateButton" onClick={revealState}>
        Log state
      </button>
    );
    setButton(el);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {button}
      <button onClick={changeState}>Change state</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Clicking on the 'Log state button' successfully logs `num` state. Clicking on the 'Change state button' successfully changes `num` state. Re-clicking the 'Log state button' doesn't log the updated value of state - it logs the old one.

1. Why is this? My guess is that, since `useEffect` runs only the once, it references only the first `revealState` function which references only the first `num` variable. Because it's not in the component's `return` statement it doesn't get 'refreshed'.
2. Whatever the cause of the problem, what're some work-arounds? Some of the requirements are:

- the tag can't be rendered directly in the `return` statement.
- we have to have the `useEffect` that's there and it needs to have a dep array of some sort (its undesirable for it to fire every-time the function component is re-executed).
- In the real project, some important changes to the tags `useEffect`'s callback renders might get made - therefore it's impractical to re-run the `useEffect` by putting something like `num` in its dep array.

Comment: Why are you mounting elements from the useEffect hook?

Comment: remove that empty array at the end of the useEffect() and let me know the result

Comment: @theTradeCoder The second sentence in point 2 lets you know I'd like to keep this

Comment: Using that array at the end, it force useEffect() to run only once on each time loading/reloading

Comment: checkout the answer below whether that helps your need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, the neatest solution is to simply add the updated event listener, every time the page is rendered:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  el.onclick = onClickHandler
});
```

The event listener always has access to the latest state (and props). IMO, this solution is more scalable than previously-mentioned solutions - if my event listener has to track the latest versions of multiple state & props, this could get messy. With this, all I need to do is add extra listeners in into this one useEffect callback. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from "react";

export default function App() {
  let [button, setButton] = useState(null);
  let [num, setNum] = useState(5);

  const revealState = useCallback(() => {
    console.log(num);
  }, [num])
  function changeState() {
    setNum(Math.random());
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const el = (
      <button id="logStateButton" onClick={revealState}>
        Log state
      </button>
    );
    setButton(el);
  }, [revealState]);

  return (
    <>
      {button}
      <button onClick={changeState}>Change state</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

you can listen to the revealState in useEffect. which gets initialized only when num is changed achieved using useCallback. so whenever you click the button the num is changed which initializes the revealState function and not initialized on other rerenders

Comment: Does work but I can't re-run the `useEffect` because some important changes to the tags might get made elsewhere. I've amended my question to say that the solution should reflect this. Thank-you though.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add `num` as dependency to `useEffect`:

```
  useEffect(() => {
      const el = (
          <button id="logStateButton" onClick={revealState}>
              Log state
          </button>
      );
      setButton(el);
  }, [num]);
```

Comment: This does work however I can't re-run the `useEffect` as some important changes to the tags might get made. I've amended my question to include this now. Thank-you though. Perhaps you could take a look at my attempted solution on the last sandbox link hyperlinked in the question? I wonder if my problem is a standard problem & if there's a standard solution.

Answer (score 0):

After more clarification on your problem it seems you need to watch over both the num and the HTML state. Combining both Alan and kishore's code together is the solution. Since the useEffect is only watching the num in Alan's answer so if any changes to the tag will not cause it to rerun. kishore also mentioned another fix which is to use the useCallback but what needs to be watch is the `button` and not the `num`. Like this:

```
const updateButton = useCallback(function (newButton) {
    setButton(newButton);
  }, [button])

useEffect(() => {
    const el = (
      <button id="logStateButton" onClick={revealState}>
        Log state
      </button>
    );
    updateButton(el)
  }, [num]);
```

This will tell useEffect to watch `num` and will return a new `button` only when `button` state is changed.

Comment: This would get verbose if we had many onClick handlers with different callbacks. Do I really want to re-render the tags each time? Especially when important changes to my tags may have taken place from elsewhere that I'd now be overwriting? Surely there must be something simpler.